# how to populate with mongdb package using typescript with model interface in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am using typescript with this interface (of the model), named invoice.ts:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

interface Invoice {
 _id: ObjectId;
 accountId: ObjectId;
 number: string;
 invoiceDate: Date;
 amount: number;
 paymentDate: Date;
 expectedPaymentDate: Date;
 updatedAt: Date;
 createdAt: Date;
 paymentAt: Date;
 repaymentAt: Date;
 reservation: object;
 totalCosts: number;
}

export { Invoice };
```

I want to retrieve all invoices with the name of the accountId which is an object and the number + id + createdAt of the Invoice

In the service-loans.ts

I have tried this:

```
  import { Invoice } from "../models/invoice";
  import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
  import logger from "../lib/logging/logger";

  const url: string = process.env["MONGODB_URL"] || "";
  const dbName: string = process.env["MONGODB_DATABASE"] || "";
  const client = new MongoClient(url);

  const getInvoices = async () => {
   try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const invoiceCollection = db.collection<Invoice>("invoice");
    const invoices = await invoiceCollection
     .find(
      {},
       {
        projection: {
         accountId: 1,
         number: 1,
         id: 1,
         createdAt: 1,
        },
       },
      )
      .populate([{ path: "accountId", select: "name" }])
      .lean();
   }
   catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
   }

 };
 export default { getInvoices };
```

It gives an error by populate saying: Property 'populate' does not exist on type. ts(2339). I need the name of the path "accountId"

Does anyone know how to make the query correct?

Comment: Never heard of population in mongodb methods (for example, in order to populate a field in mongodb shell you must execute an aggregation)
Is there any chance that you mistaken a mongoose guide for a mongodb guide?
Maybe you are using the mongodb library instead of the mongoose library

Comment: Yes, it is true that populate is used in mongoose. I am wondering is there is a simular functionality in MongoDb.

Comment: So what's the sense of your question? if you already know that method doesn't exists, why to put `.populate` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately mongoDB does not support population natively

I raccomend you using `mongoose` library or doing a `lookup` in an aggragation ([documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/))